# Using expect interact, inside of a bash script, exits bash script prematurely

Tags: bash, expect

When I use ***expect interact*** inside of a bash script to manually request the root password, it accepts the password, elevates to the root user, but exits without completing the rest of the bash script.

I am migrating users from old CentOS machines to new RHEL machines. I have a process for doing this manually, but am attempting to automate the process. I have most of it working, but a couple of the steps require root level permissions. I am attempting to use expect interact from within the bash script to perform the ***su*** command to ensure the root password remains secure.

```
#!/bin/bash

elevate()
{
    echo 
    echo "You must be logged in as root to continue."
    echo "Press [Enter] to login as root."
    /usr/bin/expect -c 'expect "\n" { eval spawn su; interact }'
}

User=`whoami`
if [ $User != "root" ]
then
    elevate
fi

echo "script completed"

exit
```

If I am logged in as root when I start the script, it never executes the elevate function and I get the "*script completed*" response. If I am logged in as any other user, the elevate function executes, I manually enter the root password, and the script exits without providing the "*script completed*" response, yet I am still logged in as the root user.

Comment: The `eval` command is not adding any benefit here, you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are not root, `su` asks for the password then starts a root shell. You are now `interact`ing with that shell.

> I manually enter the root password, and **the script exits** without providing the "script completed" response, yet I am still logged in as the root user.

I believe you are incorrect in stating "the script exits". Check `pstree -s $$` and I bet you see an expect process in there.

When you exit that root shell, then the `su` process will end, the `interact` command will return, the `expect` script will exit, the `elevate` function will return, and then you will see the "completed" message.

Comment: If you're right, then it means the OP is not executing any commands from the script as root. Would changing `spawn su` command to `spawn su root ./someOtherScript` allow the commands in *someOtherScript* to run as root?

Comment: The root commands are not *scripted* -- the user is dropped into an interactive shell and can type anything at all